# How to keep a property in an object?

Tags: javascript, object, async-await

I have a method with a parameter called project.
If I log this, it is a bigger object with a lot of properties. One of them is "`metrics`".

```
console.log(project)
// this will show the whole object with my needed "`metrics`". Just to make it clear. Inside of project is the property metrics with the data I need.
```

Now I specifically need metrics. So, I tried this:

```
console.log(project.metrics)
```

This is always undefined. How can that be if the above log shows me the object with the metrics. I tried a workaround with `setTimeout` to "wait", I tried Promises with async/await. Somehow metrics gets lost although I could log it one line before.

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Does the log only show the object properties once you "expand" it in the console? Or can you see the properties without expanding?

Comment: The console evalueates objects lazily. Look for a line like `something.metrics = ...`

Comment: If you log `console.log(JSON.stringify(project))`, you probably won't see `metrics` property at all because it is undefined when `project` was logged.